# Windows Server 2016 upgrade with no human interaction

Tags: windows, automation, windows-server-2012

In my organaisation we have over 1000 VM with Windows Server 2012 R2. 
We are planning to upgrade all the VMs to windows server 2016.
I just wanted to know if we can do that with no human interaction. 
To be specific we don't need to install them with new setup, we just need them to UPGRADE.
Can anyone please let me know how is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by something that is called "unattended update".

The installation steps are pretty straightforward ([described here in detail](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36609.windows-server-2016-unattended-installation.aspx)):

- Create an installation folder in one of the host server drives and copy the syspreped image and the unattend.xml file in it
- Review the PowerShell code and arm the appropriate variables.
- Start the rest of the installation by using the PowerShell commands.

there is no "standard" way to prepare the xml and the powershell code since it depends on your specific requirements.

You should give it a try and post a new (and specific) question if you run into troubles so we can help you.